# TRIGGER EXECUTE WITH LOOP UPTO MATCH SYSDATE

Tags: oracle, function, oracle11g, triggers, procedure

the case is that date when match with sysdate that time only need to execute that trigger

THIS IS THE CASE I NEED

```
select * from TANSDET


vechno                                  sms                             mobno     EXPDATE
===========================================================================================
TN 63 M 9276    Insurance Expire For - TN 63 M 9276 At  - 26-SEP-20    9787629787   26-SEP-20

TN 37 CH 0054    Insurance Expire For - TN 37 CH 0054 At  - 10-OCT-20    9787629787    10-OCT-20

TN 55 AA 7611    Insurance Expire For - TN 55 AA 7611 At  - 03-NOV-20    9787629787   03-NOV-20


INSERT INTO SMS_TABLE (UID,SMS,MOBNO)VALUES (SELECT (SELECT MAX(NVL(UID,1))+1 FROM TANSDET)UID,SMS,MOBNO FROM TANSDET)
```

/*WHEN AND WHICH EXPDATE MATCH WITH SYSDATE THAT TIME THIS TRIGER NEED TO EXECUTE */

Answer (score 0):

If trigger has to fire only when certain condition is met, a simple option is to include

```
if :new.expdate = trunc(sysdate) then
   ... 
   do whatever trigger is doing
end if;
```

---

Apart from that, code you use to select `UID` value is **wrong** and it'll fail in a multi-user environment because sooner or later two (or more) users will fetch the same MAX value and - if there's a primary (or unique) key constraint defined on that column - insert will fail. Switch to a sequence.

Comment: It's working fine and that (uid) field daily once only this table is going access for sending alert sms to transport incharge so it's working thanks again

Comment: and sir can i get the advice for easy way to download the attendance data from ESSL machine to Oracle server.

Comment: I don't know anything about ESSL machine, sorry. Perhaps you should open a new question as this is entirely new problem.